# Best practice for handling invalid "limit" in a paginated API?

Tags: api, pagination

I'm building an api endpoint that provides pagination via a `limit` parameter.

It defaults to 10, and has a max of 100.

If a request includes a `limit` outside the allowed range, what should I do?

For example, if a `limit` of 105 is requested, should I process the request with a 100 `limit`, ignore it and use the default value (10), or respond with an error informing the client of the permissible range?

Other examples I'm wondering about are `limit: 0`, `limit: -1`, `limit: "garbage"`

The response payload will specify what limit was used in processing the request. Nonetheless, I'm inclined to respond with an informative error rather than try to infer what the client wants. Is that overkill?

What's considered best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return HTTP 400 - Bad Request. You should only return valid data if the response matches the expactations of the client.